# Hitting button outside a form to call submit on Submit button in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have a form with hidden submit button, and I input values in it, then I hit one button and dialog appears with Confirmation message and Confirm button. When I click on Confirm button, I click also on a hidden submit button from a form. Is that possible and how can I achieve it in JQuery?

Comment: You don't have to do all that. Just put a regular `<input type=submit>` button, or a `<button>` in your form, then catch the "onSubmit" event to put up your confirmation.

Comment: I will have to. Since I have following hierarchy : <form> <dialog> <submit> </submit> <dialog> </form> and my DOM gets somewhere below and won't get fired once I get clicked on submit inside a <dialog>

Comment: Also, <dialog> is hidden until button that is located outside a <form> is fired. I will have to wrap <submit> inside a dialog with yet another <form> but it's not allowed in Tapestry, so I will have to get a work around with you guys. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jQuery use code like this:

```
$("#confirmationButton").on("click" , function () {
     $("#submitButton").trigger("click");
});
```

or

```
$("#confirmationButton").on("click" , function () {
     $("#form").submit();
});
```

Rememer that you have to set ids to your form and/or formSubmitButton.

Comment: Thank you. The other example worked like a charm on my problem. :)